# Why do we discard the constant 1 in proving that $2^{n+1} = O(2^n)$

Tags: algorithm-analysis

In [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4856107/is-22n-o2n)
someone said:

> $n + 1$ is approximately equal to 1 for $2^{n+1} = O(2^n)$.

I don't understand this point. For example, in this example:

$$ n + 1 \leq c \cdot n $$

for some $c$ and some $n \geq n_0$, the right-hand side will always be at least the left-hand side.

But here: $$ 2^{n+1} =O(2^n)$$

the left-hand side will always exceed the right-hand side.

Comment: You mixed $n^2$ and $2^n$. They're not the same thing.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

No, there exists such a constant. Indeed take $c=2$, then
$$\forall n \in \mathbb{N}\quad 2^{n+1}=2^1 \cdot 2^n \le  c \cdot 2^n.$$
So $2^{n+1}=O(2^n)$.

Comment: Oh, you could do $2^{n+1}$ = $2^1$.$2^n$. Thanks, that helps now.